# Token passing in ring algorithm in nesC/TinyOS

Tags: networking, sensors, wireless, tinyos, nesc

How can I create a token passing protocol for motes in TinyOS?

I am trying to create a token passing algorithm that passes a token from mote to mote, however I have not been successful.